# Prove inequality transformation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, estimation

I want to show that the inequality

(1) $\int_{0}^{\infty}\vert h(t,x) \vert \varphi(x)\leq e^{-\mu(t-y_{0})} \int_{0}^{\infty}\vert h(y_{0},x)\vert \varphi (x) dx < \infty$

with

(2) $  h(t,x)=\tilde{n}(t,x)-\int_{0}^{\infty}n^{0}(y)\phi(y)dyN(x)$

is equal to

(3) $\int_{0}^{\infty}\vert mN(x)-\tilde{n}(t,x)\vert \varphi(x)dx\leq C_{0}e^{-\mu(t-y_{0})}\int_{0}^{\infty}\vert mN(x)-\tilde{n}(y_{0},x)\vert \varphi(x)dx dx$

with

$m=\int_{0}^{\infty}n^{0}(x)\phi(x)dx.$

My idea was just du insert (2) into (1), but then I don't know where the $C_0$ and the second dx gets from. And I'm not sure if the second dx is a mistake or there on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Given that
$$m=\int_{0}^{\infty}n^{0}(x)\phi(x)\ \mathrm dx$$
We have
$$h(t,x)=\tilde{n}(t,x)-mN(x)$$
For the left hand side, we have
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left|h(t,x)\right|\varphi(x)\ \mathrm dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left|\tilde{n}(t,x)-mN(x)\right|\varphi(x)\ \mathrm dx$$
For the right hand side, we have
$$e^{-\mu\left(t-y_0\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left|h(y_0,x)\right|\varphi(x)\ \mathrm dx$$
$$=e^{-\mu\left(t-y_0\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left|\tilde{n}(y_0,x)-mN(x)\right|\varphi(x)\ \mathrm dx$$
The extra $\mathrm dx$ on the right hand side of your post is a typo and $C_0$ is most likely a positive constant. Without more information, we cannot tell where $C_0$ actually comes from. You were pretty much on the right track.

Comment: Why can I just write $m=\int_0^\infty n^0(x)\phi(x)dx$ for $m=\int_0^\infty n^0(y)\phi(y)dy$? Because in (2) the integral is in y and for (3) the integral is in x. Can the positive constant can get from this?

Comment: @orangejuice12, what happens if we substitute the bound variable $x$ with $y$? Does the value of $m$ change? Let $A\le B$, does multiplying $B$ by a positive constant change the result of the inequality?

Comment: No it doesn't, so I can just do it.